# Log out using forms authentication in SP2010

Tags: forms-authentication, sharepoint-2010

I have configured an intranet using Claims based authentication and an extended internet site using forms based authentication in SP 2010

All is set up and working except logging out...

I have a loginstatus control which I have placed a linkbutton inside the loggedin template.
When I click the button to log out, I have used:

```
 Session.Abandon();
        Response.Cookies.Clear();
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

And a custom redirect.
~However when I get redirected back to my home page the system still says that Im logged in and I navigate around the site. How else do I force a logout?

Answer (score 2):

[See this post by Sanjay Bhagia](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/9a5e7171-d86a-4c7f-a31e-23bb71e2812b#9a5e7171-d86a-4c7f-a31e-23bb71e2812b)

```
loginStatus.LoggingOut += new LoginCancelEventHandler(loginStatus_LoggingOut);
```

and in logout event, i used this code to logout the user.

```
FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.SignOut();
//WSFederationAuthenticationModule.FederatedSignOut();
WSFederationAuthenticationModule authModule = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;
SPUtility.Redirect(WSFederationAuthenticationModule.GetFederationPassiveSignOutUrl(authModule.Issuer, authModule.Realm, null), SPRedirectFlags.Default, HttpContext.Current);
```

as, with Claims, user is not authenticated with FormsAuthentication anymore rather with Federated Authentication, so we need to sign out this user from Federation. This piece of code worked for me!